# child node repeated as parent node in tree on ADF

Tags: tree, oracle-adf

I have created a tree in ADF from a single recursive view object, but the problem is that the same node is repeated in the parent node and child node like the image bellow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVbbV.png)

So can you help me please to have the child node not repeated as parent node.

Answer (score 0):

User, can you tell us your exact JDEV version, please?

Take a look at this [blog](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/32-tree-table-from-single-vo-169174.pdf) it's about af:treatable but it should work for af:tree too.

Or this part of the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-ui-master-detail-data.htm)